# How to build boost.log DLL that statically links to everything else boost?

Tags: c++, boost

I would like to use boost log library in my C++ project on Windows (VS 2010). Everything uses shared (DLL) runtime. Since my project contains multiple modules, I need to compile boost.log as a DLL. The trouble is, Boost.log depends on five other libraries: system, chrono, datetime, filesystem and thread. I don't want to drag 6 DLLs around, and I would like to link them statically in boost.log.

I tried to #define BOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK in config/user.hpp, but it did not help: when I build the log library it either builds as static (not what I want), or as a DLL referencing 5 other DLLs (not what I want either).

I need a log DLL that has all 5 dependencies linked statically in. Is it possible to achieve?

Comment: Aren't y'all sick and tired of boost log? The whole purpose of a library is to make work easier but this one just seems to demand so much.

Answer (score -1):

I think you'll want to create a separate DLL project that statically links the boost libraries you want.  Probably this project won't add any other code (other than some DllMain function that does nothing), but it will give you a new DLL (e.g., boostlibs.dll) that you can dynamically link to your application.

Comment: In order for this to work there will have to be something used. Basically it would have to be wrapped. The only other possibility i see is to create custom build scripts for this.

Comment: This could work, provided I don't use boost.log anywhere besides that DLL. However, this is not going to work, because it looks like "thread" library insists on being a DLL (can't statically link), and it carries 3 other boost DLLs together with it. Argh.

Comment: @Ivan Krivyakov, I'm able to statically link the thread library just fine.  I do see this comment in user.hpp about Boost.Threads "can only be dynamically linked", but I don't think that comment is applicable anymore.

Comment: @Vinzenz, I may be mistaken, but I think all that is needed to get the functions to show up in the resulting dll is for them to be declared with __declspec(dllexport).  A quick test on my system shows this is possible with boost libraries by #define'ing BOOST_HAS_DECLSPEC and BOOST_THREAD_BUILD_DLL.

Comment: @Aaron. I think I built the whole boost with link=static, and thread library simply was not built. But I may be wrong, I will double check.